# Bot no longer turning on (Discord.js v13)

Tags: discord.js

I have a simple discord.js bot coded, but whenever I do "bot.login(process.env.TOKEN)", it simply doesn't work and no errors are logged. All I could find was when I used "client.on('debug', console.log)", which returned the following:

```
Hit a 429 while executing a request.
    Global  : false
    Method  : get
    Path    : /gateway/bot
    Route   : /gateway/bot
    Limit   : Infinity
    Timeout : 499ms
    Sublimit: 3199000ms
```

Anyone know what this means or how I could possibly fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means your bot is [rate-limited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429). There are a few solutions here:

1. Wait a bit, so that the timeout completes
2. If you are using replit or any hosting, type `kill 1` in the terminal and try again

And lastly, make sure you don't have any loops requesting to the API. Requests to the API include fetching data from the API or modifying things.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older question but I've been struggling with this issue for a while and finally found a solution.

If you are hosting your bot on Replit.com every process shares an IP address with others and if someone else gets rate-limited everyone that is sharing that IP address will also get rate limited.

You can manually change your IP address on Replit by typing "kill 1" in the shell. This will stop the bot and you'll need to hit "Run" again.

**Discord v13:**

I've found an automated workaround that goes in your main file (index.js, main.js, etc...):
This goes at the top of the file:

```
const { exec } = require('node:child_process');
```

This can go anywhere in the main file:

```
//sends a kill 1 command to the child node if there is a 429 error
client.on("debug", function(info){
        let check429error = info.split(" ");
        //console.log(`info -> ${check429error}`); //debugger
        if (check429error[2] === `429`) {
            console.log(`Caught a 429 error!`); 
                exec('kill 1', (err, output) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error("could not execute command: ", err);
                        return
                    }
                  console.log(`Kill 1 command succeeded`);
                });         
        }
});
```

Your bot will go offline for approximately 5 minutes and then start up again as long as you have a process that always keeps it live.

**Discord v14:**

Add this to the top of your main file (index.js, main,js, etc...):

```
const { get } = require("https");
```

Add this anywhere before your client.login() line:

```
//checks for 429 errors at startup and every 5 minutes
function handleRateLimit() {
    get(`https://discord.com/api/v10/gateway`, ({ statusCode }) => {
        if (statusCode == 429) { process.kill(1) }
    });
};
handleRateLimit();
setInterval(handleRateLimit, 3e5); //3e5 = 300000 (3 w/ 5 zeros)
```